# Is there intention to build a read_sas7bdat() function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Many companies, including my own, use SAS for data management. Therefore many of the data analysis/manipulation tools are built in SAS as well, working with sas7bdat files. These could be progressively replaced by Python tools.

Pandas 'read_sas7bdat()' and 'to_sas7bdat()' functions would really help in this transition. Is there the intention to build this in coming milestones? I mean specifically in pandas, not a separate sas7bdat package.

Thanks,

Comment: this is probably not the correct place to ask this, you should post a feature request to [pandas github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do so and delete this. What do you recommend, making a 'New Issue'? Not sure of the best way on GitHub

Comment: You can check out my answer for a link to an existing issue.

Comment: I'll leave this question here in case anyone comes looking with the same question. Thanks to you both for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4052) is the github issue related to adding sas import functions. If you scroll to the end you can see that it's a continuing conversation. To summarize the last couple posts, there are no near-term plans, but an experimental R implementation suggest that *someday* it might happen.

In the meantime, the best way to link the two is probably through exporting CSV files.